# ClassPathXmlApplicationContext reading file outside of JAR

Tags: java, spring, classpath

My code instantiates a spring instance using the following code:

```
String filePath = "applicationContext.xml";
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(filePath);
```

This works if I put a file named "applicationContext.xml" in the root of a jar in my WEB-INF/lib folder. However, I would prefer to have a file named "applicationContext.xml" in my WEB-INF/classes folder. I have tried the following values for filePath and all of them generate a FileNotFoundException:

```
applicationContext.xml
/webappName/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml
/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml
classes/applicationContext.xml
```

None of these has worked. What is the correct syntax to use with ClassPathXmlApplicationContext to read an xml file out of the WEB-INF/classes folder?

Comment: Is `WEB-INF/classes` in your program's classpath? `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` can read files only from the classpath.

Comment: Try `/applicationContext.xml`

Comment: Where are you instantiating your spring context? Inside a a custom `ServletContextListener`? `/WEB-INF/classes` should be on the classpath for a webapp deployment something else must be going on. Need more details.

Comment: @nico_ekito - I retested and that seemed to work.

Comment: @nico_ekito: You should post that as an answer, and get credit for it.

Answer (score 2):

As commented below, you should try `/applicationContext.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Use FileSystemXmlApplicationContext